# How to convert a numeric value into a percentage (or) append percentage symbol to a number?

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to use LESS css to do the following:

```
width: ((480/1366)*100)+'%';
```

The problem though is that the output becomes:

```
width: 35.13909224011713 '%';
```

How do I make it workable? ie.:

```
width: 35.13909224011713%;
```

Answer (score 13):

It is possible to use [string interpolation](http://lesscss.org/#-string-interpolation):

```
@myvar: ((480/1366)*100);
width: ~"@{myvar}%";
```

That will output

```
width: 35.13909224011713%;
```

Additionally, if you want it to be rounded, you can use `round()`.

Comment: Anyway I can do it without the var? I tried 

width: "@{(237/768)*100}%";

But it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Hey, it's me again! Turns out it becomes a string when you do it like this. I need a number... i.e the end result is width: "35.13909224011713%"; So I'm afraid this won't work.

Comment: Turns out you also need to escape the string! So here's the correct solution with a ~ sign:

    @myvar: ((480/1366)*100);
    width: ~"@{myvar}%";

Comment: Turns out you also need to escape the string! So here's the correct solution with a ~ sign:

    @myvar: ((480/1366)*100);
    width: ~"@{myvar}%";

Comment: Well it worked without the `~` using less 1.1.3, but I edited my answer with it anyway.

Comment: The code ~"@{myvar}%" looks totally confusing for something so simple. I think this might be more easily readable: width: percentage((480 / 1366));

Answer (score 8):

Even though this question is quite old, I want to add a few more examples about adding. Less will set your units to whatever is being operated on.

```
10px + 20px
```

will output 30px

```
(20/200) * 100%
```

will output **10%**

So with units you dont need to concatenate the unit measurement.

I have found that adding 0 helps when you dont know what the unit value might be.

```
.mixin(@x, @y){
    @result: (@x / @y) * 100;
}

.my_class {
    .mixin(20, 100);
    width: @result + 0%; // you can use any unit here
}
```

The above class will have a width of 20%. If we added with px, it would be 20px.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the least verbose and most obvious method is sort of missing here (it's in Richard Testani answer actually but there it's hindered with further code leading to a wrong direction). So... 
The answer to original:

```
width: ((480/1366)*100)+'%';
```

is as simple as:

```
width: (480/1366*100%);
```

---

Speaking of `percentage`:

> it does the trick too but personally I'd never use it for its verbosity and non-readability. At quick scanning `percentage(480/1366)` reads just like `peekabooze(480/1366)` so you have to stop and stare at it to get a clue. Contrary the explicit appearance of `%` in `480/1366*100%` (or `480 / 1366 * 100%`) makes it more easily noticeable.

Comment: A bit off topic but is there a plan to expose the precision value as a compiler option?

Comment: @Harry, nope (no use-cases, see [#1909](https://github.com/less/less.js/pull/1909)).