# Less does not compute arithmetic expressions

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

I'm working in this code:

```
.vertical-align (@numoflines) {
  @first: (55 - (@numoflines * 5)) / 100;
  @result: percentage(@first);
  top: @result;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(@result * -1);
  -ms-transform: translateY(@result * -1);
  transform: translateY(@result * -1);
  position: relative;
}

.back {
  .vertical-align(1);
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

It compiles ok but when I inspect the code in Chrome it says that the `@result` is not a number (NaN%).

P.S: If a try this code in http://lesstester.com/ it works fine so i'm a bit messed up

Comment: Looks like http://lesstester.com/ and your project have different [`--strict-math`](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-strict-math) settings (lesstester: off (default) and in your project it's on). To make your code compilable with either setting always add parens around arithmetic expressions, i.e.: `@first: ((55 - @numoflines * 5) / 100);` (in your snippet with `--strict-math=on` the statement will result in a list of values instead of a single value hence `percentage` returns NaN for it.)

Comment: Btw., also a good idea would be to learn how to get the same in a more clean way [w/o using `percentage`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28058384/2712740) at all (it's sort of unrelated but curiously this way it would make the error more easily noticeable, as that incorrect list of values would appear directly in the inspector).

Comment: Btw. (oooph, sorry, for chainging comments), also `translateY(@result * -1);` with `--strict-math=on` should be  `translateY((@result * -1));` otherwise it results in incorrect CSS too... Yes, in fact `--strict-math=on` is usually [pain in the ass](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1872#issuecomment-35146481)... So at some point it could be reasonable to consider if you can turn it off (though it's not always possible, depending on the libraries your project uses, e.g. recent Bootstrap version require it to be on - unfortunately).

Comment: @seven-phases-max You could write your comments as an answer, they solved my issue too. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(So to not leave this one w/o an answer, though it's a bit broader than I'd like it to be):

Most likely `lesstester.com` and your project have different [`--strict-math`](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-strict-math) settings (`lesstester`: `off` (default) and in your project it's `on`).

To make your code compilable with either setting always add parens around arithmetic expressions, i.e.:

```
@first: ((55 - @numoflines * 5) / 100);
```

(in your snippet with `--strict-math=on` the statement will result in a list of values instead of a single value hence percentage returns `NaN` for it.)

Additionally, other statements in the snippet require parens too (if compiled with `--strict-math=on`). For example

```
translateY(@result * -1);
```

should be

```
translateY((@result * -1));
```

otherwise it results in invalid CSS like `transform: translateY(180deg * -1);` too.

Yes:

> in fact `--strict-math=on` is usually [pain in the ass](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1872#issuecomment-35146481)... So at some point it could be reasonable to consider if you can turn it off (unfortunately it's not always possible and depends on the libraries your project uses, e.g. recent Bootstrap versions require it to be on for example).