# less css multiply variable with percentage

Tags: css, less

It is possible to convert a variable to a percentage?
The below does not work I get calc(1675%) in the generated css

```
@hex-width : 67px;
margin: 1px calc(25% * @hex-width);
```

Comment: We're confused as to what you want. Could you post expected CSS output?

Comment: what Matt Way suggest is correct I just thought you could calculate a percentage of a variable without using decimal notation

Comment: Alright! Make sure to accept their answer. For completeness sake, I added and updated my answer on what I thought your question was.

Comment: Don't use `calc`. Do `margin: 1px (@hex-width * 25%/100%);` or simply `margin: 1px (@hex-width * .25);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a numeric value into a percentage (or) append percentage symbol to a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978626/how-to-convert-a-numeric-value-into-a-percentage-or-append-percentage-symbol-t)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use decimal notation:

```
@hex-width : 67px;
margin: 1px calc(0.25 * @hex-width);
```

Comment: I think he wants to get 25% width of the parents width, not a fourth of @hex-width

Comment: I'm not sure that is clear. He said he wants a variable to a percentage, nothing to do with the parent (but I could be wrong).

Answer (score 0):

What I thought you meant was this:

```
margin: 1px ~"calc(25% * @{hex-width})";
```

which would output

```
margin: 1px calc(25% * 67px);
```

Note that this isn't the same as using the float `0.25`! The above CSS will get a quarter of the parent's widthn abd multiply it with 67px.

To understand what's going on in LESS, see [the documentation](https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j/wiki/Less-Language-Escaping#syntax). First you override less's own calc-function: you want to echo calc() as is. However, you still want to use a variable in there, so you use [String interpolation](https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j/wiki/Less-Language-String-Interpolation).